# Efficient iteration of large text file

Tags: scala, iterator, bigdata

So I have the following:

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("""C:\Users\something\workspace\""" + fileName)
val lines = bufferedSource.getLines
```

I would like to select at random, a start index and an end index and iterate through `lines` in this range while printing to a new file. Is there a way to access the elements in `lines` iterator by index?

My first attempt was to copy over the data to a `ListBuffer`:

```
var lineArr = ListBuffer[String]()
for (line <- lines) {
    lineArr += line
}
```

Therafter if I iterate through `lineArr` in my range, by index, it is really slow.

In what way could I do this efficiently?

Sidenote: If I iterate through `lines` which contains all elements (which I do not want) it is fast to iterate while writing them to a new file, however I only want a select amount to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of iterating through each line I solved this problem by using slicing. I still create a `ListBuffer` but I slice it on the start and end index:

```
lineArrTemp = lineArrTemp.slice(start, end)
```

And thereafter simply iterate through the `ListBuffer` iterator, it is efficient.

Comment: `lineArrTemp.iterator().slice(start, end)` is even better. No need to create an intermediate `ListBuffer`. Or you could use `ArrayBuffer` where `slice` (but not `iterator().slice`) will be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
  lines
    .drop(startIndex)
    .take(endIndex - startIndex)
    .foreach(writeToFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider also `zipWithIndex` on the iterator, hence we can sophisticate the line selection based in the index value; for instance select even indexed lines with

```
io.Source.fromFile("temp.txt").getLines.zipWithIndex.foreach { 
  case (line,i) => if (i % 2 == 0) println(line) 
}
```

Here we index one line at a time as we iterate over the file once only.